# ES6 self executing import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have require which executes itself and saves result into variable

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

I am playing with Babel and trying to figure out how to do this in ES6. Now obviously I could do something like

```
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();
```

But I was wondering if there is some nice one liner way to do it, like with require.

Comment: It's not possible. Import does not return a value. For cases such as this, it's not bad to use require, although I guess the second version is probably going to cause fewer heads to be scratched.

Comment: Best you can do if you don't have dynamic imports:


`import lp from 'gulp-load-plugins'; const $ = lp();`


If you have dynamic imports:

`const $ = (await import('gulp-load-plugins'))();`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But I was wondering if there is some nice one liner way to do it, like with require.

No there is not.

Comment: If he has dynamic imports and is inside an async function:
`const $ = (await import('gulp-load-plugins'))();`